# How to avoid timing out in a Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

Google Hangouts automatically disconnect after 90 minutes or so unless you click a button saying you are still there.

Is there a way to avoid this without having to click the button? (A setting change, a userscript, whatever really.)